# Finding the Formula of the Product of $e_{i,j}$ and $e_{k,l}$ to Return Zero Matrix

Tags: matrices

My teacher for calculus this year gave a handout on the first day with an excerpt from *Rings, Fields, and Vector Spaces* by B.A. Sethuraman. The reason for this is in the beginning of Sethuraman's book illustrates what he wants and expects out of his students for his class.

"How should you read this book? The answer, which applies to every book on mathematics, can be given in one word - actively. You may never have heard this before, but it can never be overstressed - you can only learn mathematics by doing mathematics..."

The first example is to show that multiplication of matrices is not commutative:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Well, clearly the left hand side equals

\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}

And the right hand side equals,

\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}

"Mathematical insight comes from mathematical experience and you cannot expect to gain mathematical experience if you merely accept somebody else's word that the product on the left side of the equation does not equal the product on the right side."

Later on, it asks to find a pattern how matrices with nonzero numbers can multiply out to zero.

> To help you describe this pattern, you will let $e_{i,j}$ stand for the matrix with 1 in the (i,j)-th slot and zeroes everywhere else, and you will try to discover a formula for the product of $e_{i,j}$ and $e_{k,l}$ where i,j,k, and l can each be any element of the set {1,2}.

If $i = 1$, and $j = 1$

$$e_{i,j} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

If $l = 1$, and $k = 1$, what are the elements of $e_{k,l}$ or does that not even matter?

$$e_{k,l} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is the question looking to find the product of elements or is it looking for the product of the 2 matricies? Admittedly, this is my first time seeing this notation and I am a bit confused. I do know that $i$ and $l$ are the row indicies, and $j$ and $k$ are the column indicies.

Comment: The example you gave in your third para showed that $e_{11}e_{12}=e_{12}$. You are supposed to find a formula for the more general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation of $e_{i,j}$ and $e_{k,l}$ is the same notation, they just use different letters for the different indices. In other words, if $i=k$ and $j=l$ then $e_{i,j} = e_{k,l}$.

The reason why this notation is useful is as follows : given two $n \times n$ matrices $(a_{ij})$ and $(b_{ij})$, their product can be computed as follows : 
$$
(a_{ij})(b_{ij}) = \left( \sum_{q=1}^n a_{iq} b_{qj} \right). 
$$
This is exactly the formula you use to compute products "when you put your finger horizontally along the first matrix's rows and vertically along the second matrix's columns". The terms you come across horizontally are $a_{ik}$ and the terms you come across vertically are $b_{kj}$ ; you multiply those together and then you sum up, so that the $(i,j)^{\text{th}}$ coefficient of the resulting matrix is the sum above.

Now what is the $(i,j)^{\text{th}}$ coefficient of a matrix $e_{k,l}$? Well a coefficient $a_{ij}$ of this matrix is $1$ if and only if $i=k$ and $j=l$, so if we use the Kronecker $\delta$ : 
$$
\delta_{ik} \overset{def}=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } i=k \\
0 & \text{ if } i \neq k
\end{cases}
$$
then we get that $a_{ij} = \delta_{ik} \delta_{jl}$.

Suppose we start with $e_{k,l}$ and $e_{m,p}$ two matrices as above, so that we want to multiply 
$$
e_{k,l} e_{m,p} = (\delta_{ik} \delta_{jl})(\delta_{im} \delta_{jp}) = \sum_{q = 1}^n (\delta_{ik} \delta_{ql})(\delta_{qm} \delta_{jp}) = (\delta_{ik} \delta_{ll} \delta_{lm} \delta_{jp}) = \delta_{lm} (\delta_{ik} \delta_{jp}) = \delta_{lm} e_{k,p}.
$$

This means $e_{k,l} e_{m,p} = 0$ if $l \neq m$ and otherwise $e_{k,l} e_{m,p} = e_{k,p}$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and thorough response. The Kronecker $\delta$ notation is very interesting and useful.

Comment: @Jun-Goo Kwak : It takes a while and a bit of patience before being able to move the indices around, but it becomes very useful when you start seeing general patterns by using it. Sometimes computing by hand some examples tells you that the symbols are gonna work out if you try them out, but computing examples by hand never gives you proofs, so these symbols are necessary!

Comment: Yes, the indicies are taking some time for me to understand :). However, working out examples shows and where they come from and is useful. I am a little bit unsure about the very end where you are summing the elements of the coefficents of the matrix. Could you clarify how you got from $(\delta_{ik}\delta{ql})(\delta_{qm}\delta_{jp})$ to $(\delta_{ik} \delta_{ll} \delta_{lm} \delta_{jp})$? I understand after that, since $l=l$ in $\delta_{ll}$, we can use the Kronecker $\delta$ definition and it just equals 1, and then we can resubsitute our original matrix. It's very elegant.

Comment: @Jun-Goo Kwak : I just realized that since we are summing over $q$ and $\delta_{ql} = 0$ when $q \neq l$, I removed all these terms of the sum. I could've also removed all the terms where $q \neq m$, I would've gotten the same answer.

Comment: Ah, so if I summed the products to where $q=m$, then the $$\sum_{q = 1}^n (\delta_{ik} \delta_{ql})(\delta_{qm} \delta_{jp}) = (\delta_{ik} \delta_{ml} \delta_{mm} \delta_{jp}) = \delta_{ml} (\delta_{ik} \delta_{jp}) = \delta_{ml} e_{k,p}
$$ and again, due to the Kronecker definition, if $m\neq l$, then the product would be 0. Otherwise, it would just return our original matrix? That's brilliant. Thanks again for showing me this proof as well as teaching me about the Kronecker definition as well as applying it to the general matrix formula with regards to returning the zero matrix.

Comment: @Jun-Goo Kwak : Yes. Glad you had fun :)